# Factor Scores with SEM

Tags: stata, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I'm working with Stata, after SEM I calculated factor scores for each latent variable: Tech, Sleep, Training. They form together another latent variable called Result.

```
predict fs_Tech fs_Sleep fs_Training fs_Result, latent(Tech Sleep Training Result)
```

After I got scores for each subject, I got lost about the interpretation.

1. If the scores are standardized, values have a range like Z-scores?
2. Could I do a regression with factor scores?

Comment: You can do regression involving latent variables within the SEM framework without needing to calculate explicit factor scores.

Comment: I want to work with factor score for each individual and make a regression with other variables.

Comment: @TimCarter, build a full model, then. If you run regression with factor scores, your standard errors will not account for the measurement error/sampling uncertainty in the factor scores, and the measurement error will also pull them towards zero. These days, there is little excuse for not using the full `sem` model given how easy it is to specify (although they of course may take a while to run).

Comment: Check out this approach, which uses *corrected* factor score regression as an alternative to SEM: http://doi.org/10.1027/1614-2241/a000130